# Does awk run parallelly?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ssh, parallel-processing

**TASK** - SSH to 650 Servers and fetch few details from them and then write the completed server name in different file. How can do it in faster way? If I do normal ssh it takes 7 Minutes. So, I read about awk and wrote following 2 codes.

Could you please explain me the difference in the following codes?

**Code 1 -**

```
awk 'BEGIN{done_file="/home/sarafa/AWK_FASTER/done_status.txt"}
     {
        print "blah"|"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 "$0" uname >/dev/null 2>&1";
    print "$0" >> done_file
     }' /tmp/linux
```

**Code 2 -**

```
awk 'BEGIN{done_file="/home/sarafa/AWK_FASTER/done_status.txt"}
     {
        "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 "$0" uname 2>/dev/null"|getline output;
         print output >> done_file

     }' /tmp/linux
```

When I run these codes for 650 Servers, Code 1 takes - 30 seconds and Code 2  takes 7 Minutes ?
Why is there so much time difference ?

**File -** /tmp/linux is a list of 650 servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer** - with thanks to @OleTange

This form is preferable to my suggestion:

```
parallel -j 0 --tag --slf /tmp/linux --nonall 'hostname;ls'
```

> --tag    Tag lines with arguments. Each output line will be prepended
>           with the arguments and TAB (\t). When combined with --onall or
>           --nonall the lines will be prepended with the sshlogin
>           instead.
>
> --nonall --onall with no arguments. Run the command on all computers
>         given with --sshlogin but take no arguments. GNU parallel will
>         log into --jobs number of computers in parallel and run the
>         job on the computer. -j adjusts how many computers to log into
>         in parallel.
>         This is useful for running the same command (e.g. uptime) on a
>         list of servers.

**Original Answer**

I would recommend using `GNU Parallel` for this task, like this:

```
parallel -j 64 -k -a /tmp/linux 'echo ssh user@{} "hostname; ls"'
```

which will ssh into 64 hosts in parallel (you can change the number), run `hostname` and `ls` on each and then give you all the results in order (`-k` switch).

Obviously remove the `echo` when you see how it works.

Comment: I am using an HPUX Server to ssh different Servers running on different OS (like RedHat,Aix,Solaris,HPUX itself).
This HPUX server doesn't have this parallel command, nor I am allowed to install it.

Does these codes have any ill effects? Don't you recommend these? If not, then why ?

Comment: `GNU Parallel` is a Perl script - aren't you allowed to write/use Perl? Sorry, I cannot comment on what code is good or bad or what you can and can't use - all I am saying is that I believe GNU Parallel is well suited to doing your task quickly, accurately and easily. There may be other methods, that may be better or worse, that you may or may not be allowed to use - if there are, that's fine.

Comment: You will want use --nonall instead: parallel -j 0 --tag --slf /tmp/linux --nonall 'hostname;ls'

Comment: "Installation" can be as easy as copying a single perl script. Root not needed.

Comment: @OleTange Thank you again for your help and insights, Ole.

Comment: Thanks a Lot you guys. I'm new to Shell Scripting and also was afraid to install a new thing in Company's Server. But I did it in restricted environment and it helped a lot. 
Thanks a ton! :)